# Error: Unbound module Core when attempting to open Core module with utop from command line

Tags: ocaml, opam, utop

I am trying to follow along with Real World OCaml by setting up `opam`, `utop`, and the Core modules as well. [I've followed these directions](https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions) with some success. In particular, when I run `utop` without specifying the file to load, I can load Core with no issues:

```
[dswain@Dupree scratch]$ utop
Welcome to utop version 1.12 (using OCaml version 4.01.0)!                                                                                    

Findlib has been successfully loaded. Additional directives:
...

utop # open Core;;
utop #
```

So far so good. Now if I attempt to load a script from the command line with the same code:

```
[dswain@Dupree scratch]$ cat test.ml 
open Core.Std;;
[dswain@Dupree scratch]$ utop test.ml 
File "test.ml", line 1, characters 0-13:
Error: Unbound module Core
[dswain@Dupree scratch]$
```

I assume this is a configuration mistake I've made somewhere, but I'm not quite sure where.

### Setup details

I've attempted to reinstall `ocaml`, `opam`, `utop`, and `core` to no avail. I've got the following config changes that I'm aware that `opam init` made during setup:

*~/.ocamlinit:*

```
#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#camlp4o;;
#require "core.top";;
#require "core.syntax";;
```

*~/.bash_profile*

```
# OPAM configuration
. /home/dswain/.opam/opam-init/init.sh > /dev/null 2> /dev/null || true

eval `opam config env`
```

I'm running Arch Linux, and followed the steps to install `opam` via the AUR with no issues I'm aware of. I was also able to build & install all of the packages from the installation instructions without any errors I know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because utop executes a script-file before it runs `.ocamlinit` file. I'm not sure whether it is a bug or a feature, but that is how the code is written. Indeed, most users runs utop from emacs and send pieces of code to utop with `C-c C-s`.

If you're not comfortable with emacs, I can suggest to use the following workflow:

1. start utop
2. do some coding in your favorite editor
3. load code in utop with `#use "your_file.ml";;`
4. play with it, if not satisfied goto `2`.

Comment: I do use emacs, so that's not a big issue for me (not to say I'm great with it, but I do use it). I looked into it a bit more, and I also compiled the example with `corebuild` to see if that would make a difference. While I don't get the exact same error, I do get an error attempting to execute a function that's not defined on the `Float` module (which comes from Core.Std I think).

Comment: I would suppose, that the error you get with the Float module is a real one and is not caused by configuration problems.

Comment: I marked this as the answer, as it seems like trying to run utop through emacs is definitely the most simple way to make this work.